# How to create GUID Autonumber programmatically in ms access

Tags: c#, ms-access

How do I create guid autonumber field programmatically using C#?

Comment: How are you using MS Access in C#? ADO.NET?

Comment: i'm using ms access in c#. i use this query for create guid field:
"create table hede(Id Guid)" but i need guid and auto increment field creating or guid field's deafult value's set to new guid Id.

Comment: Be aware of the problems in Access which may not apply to you.  Subject: INFO: Replication and GUIDs, the Good, the Bad, and the Ugly http://www.trigeminal.com/usenet/usenet011.asp?1033

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use an Autonumber field with type ReplicationID? That way you wouldn't have to generate the GUID in code at all.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Are you wanting to alter the structure of a table to have a field that automatically populates with a unique GUID, or are you wanting to create the GUID on the fly in your code? If the latter, why wouldn't an auto-incrementing GUID field relieve you of the need to do it in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make your GUID field auto-increment, use GenGUID() as it's default value.

This works in Access using ADO.  Perhaps a similar statement will work in C#:

```
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "CREATE TABLE hede (Id Guid DEFAULT GenGUID())"
```

Comment: Is this the same as setting ReplicationID for an Autonumber field in the table designer within Access? If not, what's the difference?

Comment: Yes, that's how it's displayed in the Access UI.  He didn't say why he wants to do it from C#.

Comment: I read the question as being about populating an existing field, as opposed to adding the field to a table.

Comment: I note that the `GenGUID()` function only works from _within Access_. If you're using OLE-DB or ODBC from an external program (like C#) to manipulate an Access database then you'll get an error saying that `GenGUID()` is undefined. You'll need to use a GUID literal instead.

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful:

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;Q180841

Also, using DAO:

[What is the MS Access SQL syntax to create a field of type Hyperlink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133523/what-is-the-ms-access-sql-syntax-to-create-a-field-of-type-hyperlink)

Answer (score 1):

If its C# then

```
string myguid = Guid.NewGuid.ToString;
```

If its Access then

```
Private Declare Function CreateGuid Lib "OLE32.DLL" (pGuid As GUID) As Long
Private Declare Function StringFromGUID2 Lib "OLE32.DLL" (pGuid As GUID, ByVal PointerToString As Long, ByVal MaxLength As Long) As Long

Private Type GUID
    Guid1           As Long
    Guid2           As Integer
    Guid3           As Integer
    Guid4(0 To 7)   As Byte
End Type

Public Function CreateGUIDKey() As String
    Const GUID_OK As Long = 0    
    Const GUID_LENGTH As Long = 38

    Dim udtGUID As GUID
    Dim FormattedGUID As String
    Dim Result As Long

    Result = CreateGuid(udtGUID)

    If Result = GUID_OK Then
        FormattedGUID = String$(GUID_LENGTH, 0)
        StringFromGUID2 udtGUID, StrPtr(FormattedGUID), GUID_LENGTH + 1
    Else
        FormattedGUID = ""
    End If

    CreateGUIDKey = FormattedGUID

End Function
```

Comment: Seems CreateGuid isn't in OLE32.DLL anymore. Looks like CoCreateGuid should be used instead. See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/176790

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to run sql against a Jet or ACE connection?

```
CREATE TABLE Literal (LinkID GUID)

INSERT INTO Literal (LinkID) VALUES ({guid {11223344-1122-1122-1122-AABBCCDDEEFF}})
```

Comment: this is a only create guid field and insert new record.
i need create guid and autoincrement field.